# AngularJS: Value from Page Not Showing in Modal on Click

Tags: angularjs

I have a button (link) on a modal that when clicked (copySummaryToTask($event)) is supposed to copy data from the page's $scope element (thisRequest) into the modal's $scope element (nTask). It copies the correct data into the $scope but the data doesn't appear in the modal even though I am using $scope.$apply();

Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kDcDw5ueI2uFJ628OHzR?p=preview).

Here's my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope){

  $scope.NewTaskPane = false;

  $scope.thisRequest = {
    ID: 543,
    Title: 'Create This Wonderful SharePoint 2013 SPA',
    Request_Summary: "Rule fruit and under female she'd every signs creepeth good Night, fly lesser they're be green cattle and living tree also spirit us years two. Seasons he good under creepeth fifth air is. For morning. It creeping multiply from, saying.",
    Request_Type: 'Web'
  };

  $scope.Tasks = [
    {ID: 20, Title: 'Prototype App', Assigned_To: 'Wayne, Bruce', Status: 'Completed', TOT: 4.5},
    {ID: 21, Title: 'Develop App CSS', Assigned_To: 'Prince, Diana', Status: 'Completed', TOT: 6}  
  ];


  $scope.addNewTask = function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    $scope.NewTaskPane = true;
    $scope.nTask = {
        ID: $scope.Tasks.length + 1,
        Request_ID: $scope.thisRequest.ID,
        Title: $scope.thisRequest.Title,
        Status: 'Assigned',
        Resource_Instructions: ''
    };
  };

  $scope.copySummaryToTask = function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    //alert($scope.thisRequest.Request_Summary);
    $scope.nTask.Resource_Instructions = $scope.thisRequest.Request_Summary;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }
  } // end copySummaryToTask fn

}); // end main controller
```

and here's the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="overlay" data-ng-show="NewTaskPane">
        <div class ="preference_form wModal" id="frmPreference">
            <form name="frmNewTask" ng-submit="saveNewTask($event)">
                <span class="close-modal">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="NewTaskPane = false">close</a>
                </span>
                <h1>New Task</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <label for="description">Task Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Title" ng-model="nTask.Title">
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                    <label>Additional Instructions for Resource:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5">{{ntask.Resource_Instructions}}</textarea>
                    <button class="btn btn-link" style="float:right;" ng-click="copySummaryToTask($event)">Copy Customer Request Summary.</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="frmElementSubmit">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="CANCEL" ng-click="NewTaskPane = false" />
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="SAVE" ng-click="NewTaskPane = false" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <pre>{{nTask | json}}</pre>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="frmFull_Page">
        <h1 class="frmTitle">Edit Request</h1>
        <div class="frmBar clr-purple">
            <h3>Request Information</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="frm_pane">
            <div class="row">
                    <form name="EditSapForm" role="form">

                        <!-- ID / TITLE -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
                                <label for="req_id">Request ID:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ID" ng-model="thisRequest.ID" disabled="disabled">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-9">
                                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Title" ng-model="thisRequest.Title">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- WORK SUMMARY -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <label>Work Summary:</label>
                                <textarea name="Request_Summary" class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model="thisRequest.Request_Summary"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- WORK TASKS*** -->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col lg-12" style="margin-left:16px;">
                                        <label>Work Tasks [{{Tasks.length}}]</label>
                                        <table class="table table-striped" style="width:90%; margin:5px auto;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>TITLE</th>
                                                <th>ASSIGNED TO:</th>
                                                <th>STATUS</th>
                                                <th>TOT</th>
                                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr ng-hide="Tasks.length">
                                                <td colspan="6"><b>No Tasks Found!</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="task in Tasks">
                                                <td>{{task.ID}}</td>
                                                <td>{{task.Title}}</td>
                                                <td>{{task.Assigned_To}}</td>
                                                <td>{{task.Status}}</td>
                                                <td>{{task.TOT}}</td>
                                                <td><a href="#/edittask/{{task.ID}}">edit</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="6"><a ng-click="addNewTask($event)">Add New Task</a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON*** -->
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px;">
                            <div class="form-actions col-lg-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div> <!-- end row -->
        </div> <!-- end frm_pane -->
    </div> <!-- end frmFull_Page-->
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your view:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5">{{ntask.Resource_Instructions}}</textarea>
```

... where `ntask` should be `nTask`. Once you fix it, you won't need the `$scope.apply()`:

```
$scope.copySummaryToTask = function($event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    $scope.nTask.Resource_Instructions = $scope.thisRequest.Request_Summary;
} // end copySummaryToTask fn
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5">{{ntask.Resource_Instructions}}</textarea>
```

With

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-model="nTask.Resource_Instructions"></textarea>
```

This will do it, plus capture any new text added by the user.